# What is the difference between, a "square" and a "perfect-square", number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, terminology, square-numbers

Is, "36", a perfect square?

I know that, "4" is a perfect square.

Similarly, "1","9","25", are "perfect-square"s.

Comment: Yes, "square" and "perfect square" mean the same thing.

Comment: The "perfect", while redundant, is often used for emphasis.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=perfect+square) they are one and the same.

Comment: This seems like, if one were genuinely unsure of the difference, the internet would be shockingly unhelpful. Glad you asked.

Comment: @user40628 In number theory, a "square", without any other qualifiers, generally means a square of an integer, which is the same thing as "perfect square". Also, there are rational squares, i.e., squares of a rational number, e.g., $\frac{4}{9}$. In general, every non-negative integer (and real for that matter) is a square of a real number, so "perfect" ensures mean integer root. You may find the Quora discussion at [What is the difference between a square and a perfect square?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-square-and-a-perfect-square) interesting, & possibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

The term perfect square originates outside of the community of rigorous professional mathematicians.  It originates from the history of educators of mathematics writing elementary-school through high-school textbooks without themselves being practicing mathematicians.  Typically those textbook authors would more likely have had doctor-of-education degrees more than PhDs in mathematics.  That said (and regardless of whether there is 100% historical conformance to that stereotype), there was an intended meaning to the “perfect” as distinct from the “square”.

25.5025 is a square of 5.05 (obviously).  But the “perfect” was in this historical community of textbook-authoring educators referring to the square being an integer without any nonzero fractional/etc portion of the real (or any other, e.g., complex, quaternion, octonion) number.  The “perfect” in the context of “perfect square” is in effect synonymous with the term ‘square positive integer’.

Answer (score 0):

A *square number* can also be called a *perfect square*. So yes, the number $36$ is a perfect square, because it is the product of $6$ and itself.

Comment: 6*6=36, and this forms a square of side 6. But 9*4=36, but this forms a rectangle of sides, 9 and 4. So we see that 36 can be interpreted as a square as well as a rectangle.                                                                                                                                Where as, 1,4,9,25, etc. has just one representation of a square of side, 1,2,3,5 respectively.

Comment: Certainly $25$ can also represent the rectangle with side lengths $1$ and $25$.

Comment: 10 is a square of 3.16..... technicality, see mathisfun

Comment: Perfect squares are not only applied to integers like the number $36$ but also for other real numbers like the rational number $\frac{9}{16}$ or the decimal $6.25$.

Comment: simply untrue, they are called perfect because they are squares of integers.

Comment: @Roddy Not true, e.g. if you do a Google Scholar on  
"perfect square polynomial" you will find it used for polynomials, power series, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting how a discipline that is so reliant on the precision of its language can still have terms that are fuzzy.

Anyhow, for what it's worth, my interpretation of "square number" is any number that is formed by squaring a *natural* number (or maybe an integer at a push).
Many people refer to $a^2-b^2$ as a difference of perfect squares and that informs my interpretation of "perfect square number" as one whose square root is a *rational* number (remembering that this includes integers).

Answer (score 0):

A perfect square is when two identical integers are multiplied together to form a number.

For example, $\quad\quad2\times 2=4,\quad 3\times 3=9,\quad 4\times 4=16.$

So $4, 9, 16,$ and many others are perfect squares.

$10$ is not a perfect square, because for us to get it as a result, we need to multiply $3.16227766017$ with $3.16227766017$, which are Not integers.

Comment: Not literally correct, by the way.  $\sqrt{10}$ is a non-terminating decimal.